# Como Obter Root Selecionado Jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Galera,

boa tarde,

uma Duvida,

estou usando o  [JsTree](https://www.jstree.com/) e preciso de uma ajuda.

Quando eu seleciono os nodes filhos :[image: Arvore]

Consigo obter os mesmos através do script :

```
$('#arvore').jstree(true).get_selected().
```

Porem não consigo pegar os nodes "Pais" (estes que estão com Quadrado).

Existe uma forma de retornar todos os selecionados, filhos e pais?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui,

Caso alguém precise esses nodes "quadrados" são chamados de .jstree-undetermined.

Para pegar eles basta :

```
    var checked_ids = [];
    $("#arvore").find(".jstree-undetermined").each(
          function (i, element) {
              var nodeId = $(element).closest('.jstree-node').attr("id");
              checked_ids.push(nodeId);
          }
      );
```